# Cassandra displaying different time zones

Tags: cassandra, timezone

When I start cassandra the time displaying is correct. It is using my machines time. However, while inserting data I'm using a timestamp column. The time stamp is using UTC time zone. I want both times to sync.

When cassandra is started:

```
INFO  [main] 2017-07-25 11:46:57,933 StorageService.java:2248 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to NORMAL
```

In column :

```
 seq     | age | city      | dollar | first     | last    | last_modified                   | pick | state     | street          | zip 
 --------+-----+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+--------------------------------+------+-----------+-----------------+--------
 2100005 |  23 | Bangalore | $40000 | Sushmitha | Vegesna | 2017-07-25 06:19:12.950000+0000 | BLUE | Karnataka | 10th cross road | 500049
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When cassandra is started:
>
> INFO  [main] 2017-07-25 11:46:57,933 StorageService.java:2248 - Node
>   localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to NORMAL

This is logs that casssandra prints on console/logfile... which uses your system datetime.

When inserting data into cassandra, you can manually specify timezone, to use specific timezone.

```
Insert into table (timestamp_column1) values ('2017-07-25 00:00:00+0530');
```

When data is queried using cqlsh, timestamp columns are displayed using timezone value set in .cqlshrc file.. default is UTC timezone.
To change the display timezone change following in .cqlshrc file

```
[ui]
;; Display timezone
timezone = Etc/UTC
```

[TimeStamp in cassandra](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html)

Comment: I did not find any .cqlshrc file, rather found cqlshrc.sample file and I changed in it. But there are no changes in output.

Comment: If using windows... cqlshrc file needs to be in `C:\user\your_user\.cassandra`

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: try `locate cqlshrc`... OR refer http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlshrc.html

Comment: Thank you, but I changed the values rather than changing the settings.

Comment: I did try with the link provided, it did not work, is there anything else that could be done, other than changing values. My local machine is using IST while cassandra timestamp is using UTC. How could that be possible?

Comment: If no time zone is specified, the time zone of the Cassandra coordinator node handing the write request is used. For accuracy, DataStax recommends specifying the time zone rather than relying on the time zone configured on the Cassandra nodes..... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10397

Comment: Hey thanks, it is working. I added timezone line to cqlshrc file and installed pytz package.

Comment: hi, please is there a way to `select` and show the date and time with the timezone they were stored. because I have the problem that if I store this string ***2017-07-25 00:00:00+0900* and then `select` it, cassandra gives back **2017-07-24 15:00:00+0000'**, which is UTC, I would like to obtain the same timezone I provided when `insert`ing the data. this is happening on both the cqlsh and programmatically. thank you